# Find Zero Rows in DF #1 and Change to Zero in DF #2

Tags: pandas, find, rows, zero

I have two panda DF's with the same length of 366 rows and one column. DF #1 has randomly-placed zero values but DF #2 does not have zeros. I need to find the rows of zeros in DF #1 with zero values and change the values in DF #2 of the same rows to zero. I am trying to find the correlation between DF's #1 and 2 and need the rows of zeros to be the same in both DF's. The variable 'x' is 366x1 and 'y' is also 366x1. The 'y' variable below has NaN values and I"m converting them to zeros. Thank you for any help since I cannot seem to find a solution online.

```
#handle the NaN's - set to zero and set to zero in Vortex data for same rows
y.fillna(0)
def rsquared(x, y):
""" Return R^2 where x and y are array-like."""

slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = sp.stats.linregress(x, y)
return r_value**2
print(rsquared(x,y))
```

Comment: Are `x` and `y` DataFrame or Series? Everything in your code make them look like Series to me. Series are array-like, DataFrames are not.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to do?

```
x.loc[x.index==y[y['column']==0].index,'column']=0
```

I'm assuming both dataframes have column names as 'column' and have the same index values.

Comment: ok - you're also assuming that 'x' and 'y' are df's? What if the column names are unique as they are in my case?

Comment: ok - I've tried your solution and I"m getting this error AFTER i have confirmed (len(x)) that both x and y are of length = 366.  ValueError: Lengths must match to compare

Comment: Please share a sample of both the dfs